# iOS 4.0 Twitter Integration

Tags: ios, session, twitter, authentication, token

I am developing an application that requires login with social media (Facebook, twitter). From these services I just need to obtain the session tokens. So, when the user presses the "Login with Twitter button", I want to have a sign in method similar to what the Facebook application does, where it signs in the user and then returns with a session token.

I would like some pointers on where to start. I searched the official API documentation, but is seems developing with Oath is way complicated and demands time that I can't afford to devote at this point. I stumbled upon MGTwitterEngine, But I failed to see a way of obtaining the OAuth's session's token, and also, it hasn't been updated in 3 years! https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: +1 because the downvote is completely unjustified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the APIs and OAuth.  It would probably be more difficult and take longer to try to avoid OAuth.  Just put up the twitter or facebook login pages in a UIWebView and go from there.

Getting the oAuth token from Facebook is very straight forward, the iOS facebook API provides it.  Getting the Twitter API token is just a matter of parsing the URL that is returned to you.  Niether is very difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do the Facebook login. Twitter is more complicated. I also thought that straightforward OAuth consuming would be less painful. You mean loading a UIWebVIew with the request, and javascript parsing afterwards so that I can get the response from the web view?

Comment: Check out the source for Twitter that is given on the [link](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). I have done it using this in my app and it is working perfectly for iOS 5 and less.